# Iterating over an Array and update db asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I am using Express node, MongoDB In this App.

Idea: send Post request contains an array of objects, => check if any object is existed before, => add the 
       not existed elements to the array in the document in one shot.

problem: Each time I sent a post request only one element is added. I have to repeat 3 times in order to add an array of 3 elements.

solution tried: before I used promise.all() nothing has been added. after I used promise.all only one element is added

code:

```
   .post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
        let favstoAdd = req.body.favorites;
        let user = req.user;


        //check if the user have a favorites already and create favorites if it is not existed
        var p1 = Favorites.findOne({ user: user._id })
            .then((res_user) => {
                if (res_user !== null) {

                }
                else {
                    Favorites.create({ user: user._id, favorites: [] });

                }
            });

        //check if the dish Existed before in the favs and add them to the new filtered array 
        var altered_favstoAdd = [];


        var p2 = favstoAdd.map((fav) => {
            Favorites.findOne({ favorites: fav._id })
                .then((dish) => {
                    if (dish == null) {
                        altered_favstoAdd.push(fav);
                    }

                })
                .catch((err) => { next(err) });
        });

        var p3 = promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
            //update favorite 
            for (let i = 0; i < altered_favstoAdd.length; i++) {
                let alt_fav = altered_favstoAdd[i];
                Favorites.update({ user: user._id }, { $push: { favorites: alt_fav } }, { new: true }, (err, resp) => {
                    if (err) { next(err); }
                })
            }




        });

        //respond with the favorite item
        promise.all([p3]).then(
            Favorites.findOne({ user: user._id })
                .then((favorite) => { res.json(favorite); })
                .catch((err) => { next(err) })
        )

    })
```

I think the problem is in the map function :

```
        var p2 = favstoAdd.map((fav) => {
            Favorites.findOne({ favorites: fav._id })
                .then((dish) => {
                    if (dish == null) {
                        altered_favstoAdd.push(fav);
                    }

                })
                .catch((err) => { next(err) });
        });
```

this function does not itereate over the whole array some thing is preventing it.
any Ideas??

Comment: p2 method - Need to return the findOne method as it is in next line in curley braces. Also callback style function doesn't really work in loop. change them to promise based.

Comment: Your `favstoAdd.map(…)` returns an array of undefineds. You need to add a `return`, and a `Promise.all` call.

Comment: Also your `respond with the favorite item` is not passing a function to `then`, but rather running `Favorites.findOne(…)` immediately.

Comment: @Bergi where should i put the return statment?? I cant put it inside the loop because it will break.

Comment: @Bergi I have put respond with fav items in a function, still the same problem

Comment: @AhmadAli In the `map` callback, so that it returns the promise and the results get put in the array. There is no loop, what will break?

Comment: @Bergi not working, ireally should use await/async idea

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's unnecessary to compose `altered_favstoAdd` just to loop through it synchronously in a subsequent `.then(...)`. Instead, you should be able to run `Favorites.update(...)` in the `if (dish == null) {...}` block (and remember to return outer and inner Promises).